# Error when trying to parse a string as an int

Tags: java, string, int

In this Java program the user is supposed to guess a number from 1 to 100, and then if you press `S` it shows you a summary of the tries. The problem is that I am taking the input string and converting it to a number so I can compare it to the range, but then I also need to be able to use that string as a menu input. 
UPDATE How can i make the program go back to the menu option after the user guesses correctly. So after the user wins, i would like for the problem to display the summary report which can be otherwise accessed by using S

Here is my code

```
public class GuessingGame {
  public static void main(String[] args) {


    // Display list of commands
                System.out.println("*************************");
                System.out.println("The Guessing Game-inator");
                System.out.println("*************************");  
                System.out.println("Your opponent has guessed a number!");
                System.out.println("Enter a NUMBER at the prompt to guess.");
                System.out.println("Enter [S] at the prompt to display the summary report.");
                System.out.println("Enter [Q] at the prompt to Quit.");
                System.out.print("> ");


    // Read and execute commands
    while (true) {

      // Prompt user to enter a command
      SimpleIO.prompt("Enter command (NUMBER, S, or Q): ");
      String command = SimpleIO.readLine().trim();

      // Determine whether command is "E", "S", "Q", or
      // illegal; execute command if legal.
      int tries = 0;
      int round = 0;
      int randomInt = 0;
      int number = Integer.parseInt(command);
      if (number >= 0 && number <= 100) {
        if(randomInt == number){

                System.out.println("Congratulations! You have guessed correctly." +
                                " Summary below");
                round++;
        }
        else if(randomInt < number)
        {
                System.out.println("your guess is TOO HIGH. Guess again or enter Q to Quit");
                tries++;
        }      
        else if(randomInt > number){
                System.out.println("your guess is TOO LOW. Guess again or enter Q to Quit");
                tries++;
        }

      } else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {
         // System.out.println("Round        Guesses");
         // System.out.println("-------------------------");
        //  System.out.println(round + "" + tries);



      } else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
        // Command is "q". Terminate program.
        return;

      } else {
        // Command is illegal. Display error message.
        System.out.println("Command was not recognized; " +
                           "please enter only E, S, or q.");
      }

      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What you said isn't a problem, it's a plan. Why aren't you able to both use it as an input in your menu and convert it to an integer to compare the range?

Comment: The OP wants to know how to check if `command` is a number or not. typing S or Q will throw an `NumberFormatException` with the current code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check for the S/Q value first, then parse the string to an integer. If you catch NumberFormatException (thrown by `Integer.parseInt()`), you can determine if the input is a valid value. I would do something like that:

```
if ("s".equalsIgnoreCase(command)) {
    // Print summary
} else if ("q".equalsIgnoreCase(command)) {
    // Command is "q". Terminate program.
    return;
} else {
    try {
        Integer number = Integer.parseInt(command);
        if(number < 0 || number > 100){
            System.out.println("Please provide a value between 0 and 100");
        } else if(randomInt == number){
            System.out.println("Congratulations! You have guessed correctly." +
                        " Summary below");
            round++;
        } else if(randomInt < number) {
            System.out.println("your guess is TOO HIGH. Guess again or enter Q to Quit");
                 tries++;
        } else if(randomInt > number) {
            System.out.println("your guess is TOO LOW. Guess again or enter Q to Quit");
            tries++;
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        // Command is illegal. Display error message.
        System.out.println("Command was not recognized; " +
                       "please enter only a number, S, or q.");
    }
}
```

With this algorithm (I'm sure it can be optimized), you treat following cases:

- User enters s/S
- User enters q/Q
- User enters a non valid value (not a number)
- User enters a non valid number (less than 0 or greater than 100)
- User enters a valid number

Answer (score 1):

To check if a string is an integer, just attempt to parse it as an integer and if an exception is thrown, then it is not an Integer.

See:

http://bytes.com/topic/java/answers/541928-check-if-input-integer

```
String input = ....
try {
    int x = Integer.parseInt(input);
    System.out.println(x);
}
catch(NumberFormatException nFE) {
    System.out.println("Not an Integer");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Integer.parseInt(command) will give you NumberFormatException if the String is not valid. It is possible in your code if the user enters 'S' or 'E' which cannot be parsed to int value.

I have modified your code. Check this code  :

```
 while (true) {

          // Prompt user to enter a command
          SimpleIO.prompt("Enter command (NUMBER, S, or Q): ");
          String command = SimpleIO.readLine().trim();

          // Determine whether command is "E", "S", "Q", or
          // illegal; execute command if legal.
          int tries = 0;
          int round = 0;
          int randomInt = 0;
          if(!command.equals("S") && !command.equals("E")) {
            // Only then parse the command to string  

          int number = Integer.parseInt(command);
          if (number >= 0 && number <= 100) {
            if(randomInt == number){
```

Comment: I'd still wrap the Integer.parseInt in a try-catch block to prevent possible stupidity on the users part ;)

Comment: Yes it is always recommended to take preventive actions as user may go crazy and enter anything even if int value is expected. :-)

Comment: i tried to modify the code as you suggested but im still getting the same numberformat exception

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to convert the incoming `String` to an `int` before you check if its an escape sequence (S or Q).

Try rearranging your `if` statement to check for S and Q first then try converting the value to an `int`.

I'd also recommend you wrap the `Integer.parseInt` call (it's subsequent, reliant code) in a `try-catch` block, so you can provided an error statement to the user if they type in anything that isn't an int